# Using layouts from a mountable engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines

I am looking for a solution to the following problem:

db_core application contains only models for a small core system. The db_core application will not have any views.

On top of the db_core application we will have an admin interface. This will be a mountable engine. The admin interface will serve assets such as javascripts, css, images, etc.

Finally we will have additional mountable engines; eg. "blog", "forum", "authentication" that will be mounted on the db_core application, and all these mountable engines should have the same layout as the admin interface engine.

I have a test up and running where the db_core application serves assets, but I have not been able to find out how to let another engine serve the assets so the db_core application can remain small and free of any assets and views.

- db_core

  - Engine A -> admin interface (assets)
  - Engine B, C, D, ... -> various other engines using assets from Engine A

Comment: I found the answer in another post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042348/rails-3-2-engine-layouts

Answer (score 0):

I think you really mean an isolated engine. See "isolated" at [Engine rdoc](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html) You CAN write an engine that is mountable but not isolated -- essentially meaning it's got it's own routing, but is otherwise the same as a plain old school non-isolated engine.

But I've stopped writing my engines as isolated for just these sorts of reasons. I rarely want an engine that is actually complete isolated from the host app. There's usually view templates (if not layouts specifically) that I want the host app to have access to (and be able to over-ride with their own local template, by just naming it the same but being earlier in the load path being in the host app), and/or helper methods that I want the host app to have access to and be able to over-ride on a method-by-method basis, and/or assets i want avail in the host app, etc. Yes, you can write a generator to copy them over, but that 'freezes' them in the host app, and can be a forwards-compatibility issue.

So, personally, I find isolated engines to cause more problems than they solve. I just use an 'ordinary' engine, and DIY isolate the parts that need isolating in the right way (module namespace controllers, for instance).

Same for routing/mountable. I don't use Rails 'mountable' engines, but I also don't have my engines automatically add routes to the host app by having their own engine/config/routes.rb that gets automatically loaded. Instead, I have the (non-mountable) engine provide a method that the host app can put in it's own routes.rb (with the routing object passed as an arg), that when called will add engine-needed routing to the app. The method can take arguments to customize things (only add some routes but not others, use custom routing namespaces, whatever).

I think Rails 3 gives you all the building blocks you need with a 'plain' engine to make it integrate with the app in exactly the ways you want. The higher level abstraction of mountable/isolated, which fixes a bunch of these choices for you, results in something that's fit only for certain use cases. If you really do want an engine that's a completely isolated subsystem, sure. If you need to write an engine that works with any Rack app not just Rails, then you essentially need to run it as a completely isolated sub-system (this is how devise ends up where it is), but you are giving up a lot to do that. 
But I've come to believe it's not in fact the future of "the best way to do engines from now on, generally".

For what you're trying to do, I think making your engines isolated is going to be counter-productive. Make them not isolated.  But then there will be some stuff to figure out about how to make your engine behave with just the kinds of isolating and routing you want (and not the kinds you don't want), it's true -- this stuff is sadly not documented great.

Comment: What I was looking for was a solution on how to have the layout of one mountable engine being used by other mountable engines.

Comment: yep, I don't have an answer, I don't expect you to accept my answer. I do not believe it is possible when the layout resides in an isolated/mountable engine.  There may be a way to hack it if you can add the source engine's view directory back onto the Rails view load paths, but that's one of the things that `isolate_namespace` in an engine turns off.